# How to italicise part of correlation coefficient annotation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, italic

I cannot figure out how the make the letter "R" in the `annotate()` function below italicised on my plot.  I've tried adding in `expression()` before `paste()`, and using `italic()`, but that then pastes the section starting "round(cor..." as text, rather than the result of the calculation.

```
    ggplot(subset(crossnat, !is.na(homicide) & !is.na(gdppercapita)),
  aes(x = gdppercapita, y = homicide)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) +
  ggtitle("Figure 3: Relationship between GDP per capita ($) and homicide rate") +
  labs(subtitle = "n = 177 (17 countries removed as either GDP per capita or homicide data unavailable",
       x = "GDP per capita ($)",
       y = "Number of homicides in 2013 (per 100k of population)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,15,30,45,60,75,90)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess",
              formula = y ~ x,
              colour = "red",
              size = 0.5) +
  annotate(x = 50000, y = 75,
           label = paste("R = ", round(cor(crossnat$gdppercapita, crossnat$homicide, use = "complete.obs"),3)),
           geom = "text", size = 4)
```

Thanks

EDIT - the suggested possible duplicate does not seem to work for me. I think this might be due to the calculation of the correlation being embedded inside the `annotate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of formatting is tricky. You need to pay attention to the white spaces when the  `parse=TRUE` is used. To format the text you need proceed in two steps of pasting. Let's create a simple reproducible example:

```
ggData <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100) )
```

I recommend you to store the text AND the correlation value R outside of the `ggplot` function for readability of the code:

```
textPart1 <- "paste(italic(R), \" =\")"      # check the ?annotate example for \" =\"
corVal <- round(cor(ggData$x, ggData$y, use = "complete.obs"), 3)
```

The trick is to `paste` the two variables with the `sep="~"` instead of the white space.

```
ggplot(ggData, aes(x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = 1.5,
           label = paste(textPart1, corVal, sep="~"), size = 4 , parse=TRUE)
```